# Plot groupby data using secondary_y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I would like to plot 12 graphs (one graph per month) including columns `'A'` and `'B'` on the left y axis and column `'C'` on the right.

Code below plots everything on the left side.

```py
import pandas as pd
index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:00', '2011-12-31 23:50:00', freq='1h')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index),3),columns=['A','B','C'],index=index)

df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
for key, group in df2:
    group.plot()
```

How to separate columns and use something like this:`group.plot({'A','B':style='g'},{'C':secondary_y=True})` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can capture the axes which the Pandas `plot()` command returns and use it again to plot `C` specifically on the right axis.

```
index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1 00:00:00', '2011-12-31 23:50:00', freq='1h')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),3).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B','C'],index=index)

df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
for key, group in df2:
    ax = group[['A', 'B']].plot()
    group[['C']].plot(secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

To get all lines in a single legend see:
[Legend only shows one label when plotting with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988196/legend-only-shows-one-label-when-plotting-with-pandas/21989204#21989204)

Comment: Do you know why x ticks are different for every month ? Particularly February.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you can just do

```
for key, group in df2:
    group.plot(secondary_y='C')
```