# How to get multiple legends from multiple pandas plots

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I've got two dataframes (both indexed on time), and I'd like plot columns from both dataframes together on the same plot, with legend as if there were two columns in the same dataframe.

If I turn on legend with one column, it works fine, but if I try to do both, the 2nd one overwrites the first one.

```
import pandas as pd

# Use ERDDAP's built-in relative time functionality to get last 48 hours:
start='now-7days'
stop='now'

# URL for wind data
url='http://www.neracoos.org/erddap/tabledap/E01_met_all.csv?\
station,time,air_temperature,barometric_pressure,wind_gust,wind_speed,\
wind_direction,visibility\
&time>=%s&time<=%s' % (start,stop)

# load CSV data into Pandas
df_met = pd.read_csv(url,index_col='time',parse_dates=True,skiprows=[1])  # skip the units row 

# URL for wave data
url='http://www.neracoos.org/erddap/tabledap/E01_accelerometer_all.csv?\
station,time,mooring_site_desc,significant_wave_height,dominant_wave_period&\
time>=%s&time<=%s' % (start,stop)

# Load the CSV data into Pandas
df_wave = pd.read_csv(url,index_col='time',parse_dates=True,skiprows=[1])  # skip the units row
```

plotting one works fine:

```
df_met['wind_speed'].plot(figsize=(12,4),legend=True);
```

[image]

but if I try to plot both, the first legend disappears:

```
df_met['wind_speed'].plot(figsize=(12,4),legend=True)
df_wave['significant_wave_height'].plot(secondary_y=True,legend=True);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21989204/190597

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, thanks to the comment by unutbu pointing me to essentially the same question (which I searched for but didn't find), I just need to modify my plot command to:

```
df_met['wind_speed'].plot(figsize=(12,4))
df_wave['significant_wave_height'].plot(secondary_y=True);
ax = gca();
lines = ax.left_ax.get_lines() + ax.right_ax.get_lines()
ax.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])
```

and now I get this, which is what I was looking for:
[image]

Well. Almost. It would be nice to get the (right) and (left) on the legend to make it clear which scale was for which line. @unutbu to the rescue again:

```
df_met['wind_speed'].plot(figsize=(12,4))
df_wave['significant_wave_height'].plot(secondary_y=True);
ax = gca();
lines = ax.left_ax.get_lines() + ax.right_ax.get_lines()
ax.legend(lines, ['{} ({})'.format(l.get_label(), side) for l, side in zip(lines, ('left', 'right'))]);
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Actually, I realize this is not *quite* what I wanted.  I wanted the  legend title to be `significant_wave_height (right)` like it was originally when pandas plotted it.

Comment: `ax.legend(lines, ['{} ({})'.format(l.get_label(), side) for l, side in zip(lines, ('left', 'right'))])` will add `(left)` and `(right)` to the labels.