# Pandas legend has just one label

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, legend

I got a smilar question to: [Legend only shows one label when plotting with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988196/legend-only-shows-one-label-when-plotting-with-pandas)
I want to plot every column of some data in an extra plot (data has outliers set as mean + 10*Sigma).

The Legend should contain: Sigma and outliers above and under 3*Sigma.

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(data.columns)):
    m= data[name[i]].mean()
    s = data[name[i]].std()
    labels=[]
    labels.append('sigma: '+str(round(s,2)))
    labels.append('> 3*sig: '+str(above[0][i]))
    labels.append('< 3*sig: '+str(under[0][i]))

    plt.xticks([-10*s+m,-3*s+m,-2*s+m,-s+m,m,s+m,2*s+m,3*s+m,10*s+m],
               ['<3*s','-3*s','-2*s','-s','0','s','2*s','3*s','>3*s'])

    ax=data.ix[:,i].plot(xlim=(-11*s+m,11*s+m),
                         title=plot,
                         kind='hist',
                         bins=30,
                         legend=True)                       

    ax.legend(labels,loc='best')
    ax.set_xlabel('sigma')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Why is there only one Label in my plot?

Comment: Have you read through this?  http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Comment: Very embarrassing, thank you.