# Secondary y in pandas histogram plot. Legend is gone missing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having trouble with the legends in a simple pandas plotting task. It seems the second legend is being hidden by the first graph.

A sample of my df:

```
print(campaign.head(10))

    hour_read  hour_sent
0        16.0         13
1        14.0         13
2        13.0         13
3        14.0         13
4         NaN         13
5        13.0         13
6        13.0         13
7        16.0         13
8        14.0         13
9        16.0         13
10       15.0         15
11       16.0         15
12       15.0         15
13       15.0         15
14       15.0         15
```

I can plot both these series on the same histogram, and I am using `secondary_y'.

However I can't get the legend for `hour_read` to appear. No matter what I try with the legend options.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.xlabel('Email sent vs open hour')

campaign.hour_read.plot(kind='hist',alpha=0.8,  label='Hour Read')

campaign.hour_sent.plot(kind='hist',alpha=0.8 ,secondary_y=True, label='Hour Sent')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')


plt.show()
```

[image]

I have also tried setting up separate axes first. And using `#ax1.legend(loc=1)` and `ax2.legend(loc=2)` with many different variations. I think the `hour sent` plot is completely covering the `hour_read` legend. How can I get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777023/pandas-plot-multiple-series-but-only-showing-legend-for-one-series?

Comment: if I am not working campaign.hour_read and campaign.hour_sent both are different axes, can you try this 
        campaign.hour_read.legend(loc='upper right')
        campaign.hour_sent.legend(loc='upper right')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988196/legend-only-shows-one-label-when-plotting-with-pandas

Comment: @Pygirl this removes legends completely.

Comment: @Pygirl the second recommended link gives me the error: `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'right_ax'`

Comment: @TheGuy a variation of your comment worked. You had them both set at `upper right`. I changed one to `upper left`. You were also assigning a legend to the pandas series itself. This is what I did: `campaign.hour_read.plot(kind='hist',bins=24,alpha=0.8,  label='Hour Read').legend(loc='upper right')`

Comment: so is it working?

Comment: @TheGuy yep, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
fig=plt.figure()

plt.xlabel('Email sent vs open hour')

campaign.hour_read.plot(kind='hist',alpha=0.8,  label='Hour Read')

campaign.hour_sent.plot(kind='hist',alpha=0.8 ,secondary_y=True, label='Hour Sent')


handles,labels = [],[]
for ax in fig.axes:
    for h,l in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels()):
        handles.append(h)
        labels.append(l)

plt.legend(handles,labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you can position them also `plt.legend(handles,labels,loc='upper left')`