# Plotting multiple columns after a groupBy in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a `df` of the form

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "date": [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, x) for x in range(1, 8)],    
    "label": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C"],
    "value1": [1, 22, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "value2": [10, 4, 30, 5, 6, 8, 9]
    }
)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

I'd like to have a single plot that contains all the 6 lines: the value of `value1` and `value2` for each of the groups. I browsed other answers, but I couldn't find how to properly do it. The best I have is

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, df in grouped:
    df.plot(ax=ax, label="Value for {}".format(label))
plt.legend()
```

which produces this result:

[image]

There are two problems here (prob the same):

- I can't seem to control the label text
- the label it is useless as it it now, because it is not informative

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988196/legend-only-shows-one-label-when-plotting-with-pandas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps just use the axes to plot instead of the `DataFrame` and explicitly mention what you want to plot?

```
grouped = df.groupby('label')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, df2 in grouped:
    ax.plot(df2['value1'], label=label+' value1')
    ax.plot(df2['value2'], label=label+' value2')
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.xlabel(df.index.name)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Or if you don't want to write that out a lot of times, just specify which columns you want to plot ahead of time, and use another loop.

```
plot_vals = ['value1', 'value2']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, df2 in grouped:
    for col in df2.columns[df2.columns.isin(plot_vals)]:
        ax.plot(df2[col], label=label+ ' ' + col)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.xlabel(df.index.name)
plt.legend()
```

Comment: for some reason i thought that there is an easier pandas version of everything matplotlib. i might need to start reconsidering this

Comment: It's certainly very useful for some things. For instance, using the pandas functionality you don't need to explicitly specify the rotation, or the axis labeling. But matplotlib is always the easiest to fall back on when things don't quite work as you want.

Comment: You could use `df.pivot(columns='label').interpolate().plot()`, however points are expanded and this answer will probably be the best way since the answer mimics your desired plot