# Python: Access the legend of a chart with two y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

Using the Pandas `plot` function, it is quite simple to create a chart with a secondary y-axis. But how can I access the legend in order to change the font size or get rid of the frame or change its location, for example?

I tried to make use of the `axis.get_legend_handles_labels()` function. But this is not working as expected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (20, 2)),
                  index=pd.date_range('20190101', periods=20),
                  columns=list('AB'))

df.plot(secondary_y=['B'])

ax = plt.gca()
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the merged legend by accessing the handles and the labels from the axis objects. Here is an answer motivated by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989204/4932316) solution. Now you can specify the location, fontsize, `frameon`, etc.

```
np.random.seed(981)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (20, 2)),
                  index=pd.date_range('20190101', periods=20),
                  columns=list('AB'))

ax = df.plot(secondary_y=['B'])

lines = ax.get_lines() + ax.right_ax.get_lines()

ax.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines], 
          loc='upper left', frameon=False, fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `plot` function of `pandas dataframe`  returns the axes.

```
ax = df.plot(secondary_y=['B'])
h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```